# addHttpRequestHandler regex not matching

Tags: regex, wakanda

I am attempting to match a regex pattern in the middle of an incoming request.

I have verified my regex pattern works with regex101.com.

The documentation states that `addHttpRequestHandler` regex will match anywhere given the correct pattern.

```
addHttpRequestHandler('/clinServicesScheduled',
'Scripts/clinServicesScheduled.js', 'clinServicesScheduled');
```

The above only matches at the beginning of the request.

What is the correct pattern to match in the middle of the request?

http://127.0.0.1/data/dashboard/community/communityCode/clinServicesScheduled/month/...

http://livedoc.wakanda.org/Global-Application/Application/addHttpRequestHandler.301-636268.en.html

`/myPattern`: intercepts any requests containing `/myPattern` regardless of its position in the string. This pattern will accept indifferently requests such as `/files/myPattern`, `/myPattern.html`, and `/myPattern/bar.js`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the following regex. it looks like wakanda always matches the *urlPath* from the beginning even though it is documented differently in the docs: http://doc.wakanda.org/home2.en.html#/Global-Application/Application/addHttpRequestHandler.301-636268.en.html

```
addHttpRequestHandler('.*/clinServicesScheduled', 'Scripts/clinServicesScheduled.js', 'clinServicesScheduled');
```

i have used this before to catch patterns in the middle of a request string

Comment: Stefan, I see it now, testing... Thanks!

Comment: Stefan, '.*/thingsToMatchAnyWhere' this works!  Thanks!

Comment: Hi @DavidRingsmuth, if StefanE answer is correct, please consider marking it as accepted (with the check on the left) to allow other readers to clearly identify this answer as correct.